# Nested elements not available without autopublish in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have removed autopublish and now have simple `publish` and `subscribe` for starters.

```
Meteor.publish("records", function() {
  return Records.find({});
});
```

and

```
Meteor.subscribe('records');
```

In Mongol I can see my nested data items, which is a geoJSON object. However, when I try to access the item with here it doesn't work, unless autopublish is on...

```
Template.recordView.rendered = function() {
    var geoData = Template.currentData().loc;
};
```

I have tried just "loc" and parentData().loc. None of them are defined. What has autopublish removed that I have not put back?

Comment: This could well be an issue with data subscription. I think you got the answer below.

Comment: I will try the answer. It has the data in mini mongo and I can get top level data though which seems odd.

Comment: If you have data in the inner levels or nested, you may have to write the complete query instead of just `Records.find()`. You can get it with a few trials easily.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you subscribing to your data? I recommend that you delegate that for your template.

```
Template.recordView.onCreated(function() {
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function() {
        // Do reactive stuff here
        Meteor.subscribe("records");
    });
});

Template.recordView.helpers({
    // Data is now available here
    'geoData': function() {
        return Records.find().loc;
    }
});
```

Now you have access to your data template-level. Do whatever you want with it and return a helper. In your .html:

```
<template name="recordView">
...
{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
   {{geoData}}
{{else}}
   Loading...
{{/if}}
...
</template>
```

You'll wait for all your data to arrive before rendering the content you provided in your helper.